# Getting distinct records laravel using query builder and using raw query differs

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Laravel 5.6.29
PHP 7.3.5

```
App\StatusAudit::where('user_id', 39)->where('new_status', 4)->whereBetween(
'created_at', [\Carbon\Carbon::parse('22-05-2019')->toDateString(), \Carbon\Carbon::parse('22-06
-2019')->toDateString()])->distinct()->count()
```

gives result 31, status_audits.id is different so 31, correct, but `->distinct('video_id')` is giving 31 is interesting! and using `groupBy` giving me 1.

and

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT status_audits.video_id) FROM status_audits WHERE user_id = 39 AND new_status = 4 AND DATE(created_at) BETWEEN "2019-05-22" AND "2019-06-22"
```

is giving 30

why there is difference in result 30 and 31?

Tinker result

```
>>> App\StatusAudit::where('user_id', 39)->where('new_status', 4)->whereBetween(
'created_at', [\Carbon\Carbon::parse('22-05-2019')->toDateString(), \Carbon\Carb
on::parse('22-06-2019')->toDateString()])->distinct('video_id')->count()
=> 31
>>> App\StatusAudit::where('user_id', 39)->where('new_status', 4)->whereBetween(
'created_at', [\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '22-05-2019'), \Carbon\
Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '22-06-2019')])->distinct('video_id')->count()
=> 28

>>> App\StatusAudit::where('user_id', 39)->where('new_status', 4)->whereBetween(
'created_at', [\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '22-05-2019')->toDateSt
ring(), \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '22-06-2019')->toDateString()]
)->distinct('video_id')->count()
=> 31
```

GroupBy result

```
$ php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.9.9 (PHP 7.3.5 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> App\StatusAudit::where('user_id', 39)->where('new_status', 4)->whereBetween(
'created_at', [\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '22-05-2019')->toDateSt
ring(), \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '22-06-2019')->toDateString()]
)->groupBy('video_id')->count()
=> 1
```

**Update**
getting collection and count unique records is not efficient, but this is a workaround

```
>>> App\StatusAudit::where('user_id', 39)->where('new_status', 4)->whereBetween(
    'created_at', [\Carbon\Carbon::parse('22-05-2019')->toDateString(), \Carbon\Carb
    on::parse('22-06-2019')->toDateString()])->get()->unique('video_id')->count()
    => 30
```

Another work around is

```
>>> App\StatusAudit::where('user_id', 39)->where('new_status', 4)->whereBetween(
'created_at', [\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '22-05-2019')->toDateSt
ring(), \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '22-06-2019')->toDateString()]
)->distinct()->pluck('video_id')->count()
```

Comment: Can you show us what you mean by `groupBy` giving 1?

Comment: @CalumHalpin Updated the question, with groupby result and a work around.

Comment: I don't know why the group by is returning 1 but I've updated my answer with code that should work.

Comment: @CalumHalpin that is similar to my workarounds.

Comment: Yes but it's all handled by the database rather than fetching the list of results and counting them in PHP, which you didn't seem to want.

Comment: @CalumHalpin, right, but I am looking into some question, may be we can get a proper solutions.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a proper solution. What's the issue with the code I provided? It should translate to something very similar to your handwritten SQL.

Comment: @CalumHalpin I will post, if I will get any better solution, for now, I have accepted your answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `distinct()` method doesn't take any arguments: https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_distinct. Your handwritten SQL query is counting distinct `status_audits.video_id`s but your query builder code is counting distinct rows.

You can pass the column name to the the `count()` method to count only distinct values from that column.

```php
App\StatusAudit::where('user_id', 39)->where('new_status', 4)->whereBetween(
'created_at', [\Carbon\Carbon::parse('22-05-2019')->toDateString(), \Carbon\Carbon::parse('22-06
-2019')->toDateString()])->distinct()->count('video_id')
```

Comment: You are right there, but check there is also groupBy giving 1!

Answer (score 0):

Your date literals in the calls to `Carbon::parse` look off to me.  Try using an ISO format:

```
App\StatusAudit::where('user_id', 39)
    ->where('new_status', 4)
    ->whereBetween('created_at', [\Carbon\Carbon::parse('2019-05-22'),
                       \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2019-06-22')])
    ->distinct()
    ->count();
```

If you wanted to use `dd/mm/YYYY` format for the date strings, then you might have to use something like this:

```
$date = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '22-05-2019);
```

Comment: I have edited my question, please check, it is again different, it is 28 now!

Comment: `distinct` does not take parameters what @calcum has suggested is correct, but what about groupBy, why it is giving 1?Can you give any idea on it?